# CLI Cordova/PhoneGap project shows two www directries

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have upgraded my old Cordova android project into latest version using CLI. However when my project is built, it shows two www folders, One at root level of the project and other in the asset folder. The below screen shows its exact hierarchy.

Can some body explain me why Cordova creates two www folders. And second which directory I have to maintain and change accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project with the [Cordova 3 CLI](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli), a different folder structure from Cordova 2 projects is created.

For example, the CLI command `cordova create myApp com.example.MyApp MyApp` would create the following folder structure:

```
myApp/
|-- config.xml
|-- hooks/  
|-- www/
|-- plugins/
```

You then add target platforms using the CLI, for example `cordova platform add android` would result in:

```
myApp/
|-- config.xml
|-- hooks/  
|-- www/
|-- platforms/
| |-- android/
|-- plugins/
```

The root `myApp/www` is the master folder which you put your app code in. When you build the project for a particular platform using the CLI, the contents of `myApp/www` is copied to the target platform folder. For example, `cordova build android` will copy the contents of `myApp/www` to `myApp/platforms/android/assets/www`.

However, because your old project structure is Cordova 2, then the platform folder is actually the root folder in the project i.e. `myApp/`. So when you build you project, it's copying the contents of the master www folder `myApp/www` to the platform folder `myApp/assets/www`.

You could try to manually create the Cordova 3 project structure by creating `myApp/platforms/android` and moving all the Android-specific folders (assets/, bin/, cordova/, CordovaLib/, libs/, platform_www/, res/) and files (all files in myApp/ except config.xml) into it.

But if this fails to build, your best bet is probably to create a new project using the Cordova 3 CLI with the same signature as your old project, then move the assets across from the old project.